# Checkout a private github in Azure pipeline job using service connection

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, git-checkout

I want to checkout one of the private repo which is located in the same GitHub organization in one of the Azure pipeline stages, based on Azure documentation here is what I have tried:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: pipelinetemplates
    type: github
    name: myorg/myrepotemplate
    endpoint: mygithub-serviceconnection
  - repository: myrepo
    type: github
    name: myorg/myrepo
    endpoint: mygithub-serviceconnection
stages:
- stage:
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:
    - template: Template/build.yaml@pipelinetemplates ##It works fine
    pool:
       vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

- stage:
  jobs:
   - job: A
     pool:
       vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
     steps:
     - checkout: myrepo  ##Error-not found repo
     - task: PowerShell@2
       inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host "Fetching files"
          ls
```

I get this error message in checkout part:

```
Syncing repository: myorg/myrepo (github)
git version
git version 2.24.0
git lfs version
git-lfs/2.9.1 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.13.1)
git init "/home/vsts/work/1/s"
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/vsts/work/1/s/.git/
git remote add origin https://github.com/myorg/myrepo
git config gc.auto 0
git config --get-all http.https://github.com/myorg/myrepo.extraheader
git config --get-all http.proxy
git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic ***" fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/myorg/myrepo/' not found
##[warning]Git fetch failed with exit code 128, back off 5.284 seconds before retry.
```

Does anyone know what the problem is and how it can be fixed?

Updated:

I could see that the service-connection is using GitHub-InstallationToken (using azure pipelines app). And based on my last searches when we use GitHub token, then we can not use it more than one time for fetching repos under one pipeline however in this pipeline we are calling the GitHub service-connection two times. It looks like the token is valid for one time use. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: you sure your service connection has permissions to that repo? this looks okay

Comment: yes, I have used the same service-connection for fetching the helmchart template from another repo and it works fine in that way however it has problem using checkout.

Comment: Is the account used for service connection the same as the github account? If not, can the account used for service connection have access to a private repository on github? Try adding collaborators or create the service connection by Github PAT.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT yes, the service-connection is a GitHub user. and that user has read access to the private repos.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT How can I add collaborators?

Comment: @Matrix, you mean github collaborators? https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT but as I use a GitHub user, which exist in that GitHub organization account, as service-connection, this already is done. That user has Read access which can read, clone and pull repo

Comment: @Matrix, Yes, you are right. Have you tried other accounts with more permissions? I have test on my side, I could not reproduce this issue.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I can try with another account. what kind of permission did you have when you tested it?

Comment: @Matrix, The owner of the github repo, use the same account to create the service connection.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT please check the updated part of my question, I found where the problem is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-setting up the GitHub Service-Connection with oauth instead of oauth2 fixed the problem.